# kubectl command to update the sidecar image

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Along with the container image in kubernetes, I would like to update the sidecar image as well.

What will be the `kubectl` command for this process?

Comment: Do you want to update the version of the image deploy or the image have the same version and you want to re pull the image ?

Comment: I would like to update the version of the sidecar image.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed you have a deployment spec look like this:

```
...
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mydeployment
  ...
spec:
  ...
  template:
  ...
    spec:
      ...
      containers:
      - name: application
        image: nginx:1.14.0
        ...
      - name: sidecar
        image: busybox:3.15.0
        ...
```

`kubectl set image deployment mydeployment application=nginx:1.16.0 sidecar=busybox:3.18.0`

Answer (score 1):

kubernetes have the command `set image` that allow you to update an image to the expected version

the syntax is

```
kubectl set image deployment/{deployment-name} {container name}:{image:version}
```

with a sample it look like

```
kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.9.1
```

you can found the documentation of this command here https://kubernetes.io/fr/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#mise-%C3%A0-jour-d-un-d%C3%A9ploiement

Answer (score 0):

Besides what other users advise to use `kubectl set image` you can also `patch` your resource (`pod`, `deployment`, etc.).

In [Kubernetes Patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#patching-resources) documentation you have some examples there:

```
# Update a container's image; spec.containers[*].name is required because it's a merge key

$ kubectl patch pod valid-pod -p '{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"kubernetes-serve-hostname","image":"new image"}]}}'

# Disable a deployment livenessProbe using a json patch with positional arrays

kubectl patch deployment valid-deployment  --type json   -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/livenessProbe"}]'
```

Also you can edit your configuration YAML and apply it.

```
kubectl apply -f <yamlfile with new image>
```